# Are there Anyone that use TableViewController without subclassing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am just curious. In IB, we can put a tableviewcontroller. However, as far as I know, we always subclass that tableview controller right? That way we can implement delegate, etc.

However, it seems that for some "default" behavior, IPhone intended tableviewcontroller to be used as is. Otherwise, why would IB let us put tableViewController like that?

Are there any sample code where people use tableViewController without subclassing?

Where does they implement things like what cells to draw, etc. then?

---

I guess the right answer of the question is that it's simply ridiculous to use a UITableViewController without sub classing. No body is doing it. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am just curious.

Comment: YES..you can use uitableview without subclassing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you use a subclass of `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` you need to set the data your table is going to display, otherwise, what's the point of a blank table? To achieve that you have to subclass and implement some methods. It's also a good idea to keep the delegate and the datasource in the same controller, unless the complexity really asks for different classes.

That being said, I always create my own table controllers as a subclass of `UIViewController` and implement the table controllers methods myself, because it gives you more flexibility. Matt Gallagher has several posts on how and why. See [UITableView construction, drawing and management (revisited)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html).

If you want to give it a try, create a subclass of `UIViewController` with a XIB and add the following sample code:

```
// interface
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SettingsVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@end

// implementation
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize array = _array;
# pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.array count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int row = [indexPath row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

Then add a `UITableView` object to the XIB, link the `tableView` of the controller to the `UITableView` object, and link the delegate and datasource of the `UITableView` to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not necessary to inherit your class with tableViewController. You can use table view by simply 
putting TableViewController in xib.

and setting its delegate and datasourse to file's owner you can draw the table cells.

Comment: if we set the delegate and data source to file's owner rather than the tableViewController, then what's the point of having a tableViewController? Why not just add tableview? I suppose it can have some point but only if we subclass the tableViewController, which means back to the original question.

Comment: I think the question is "is there any case where you want to use a UITableViewController without subclassing it".

Comment: @Jim Thio, i don't think if you inherits your class with UITableView then it call the delegate and data sorce method. In case when we make Navigation based app then by default rootView is tableView and and class is inherited with UITableView also it having connectin for datasource and delegate with class owner.so making class as owner for delegate and data source is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a `UITableViewController` *as is*, it's like using a `UIViewController` without subclassing it : you can't set any inner mechanics.

But you can have a `UITableView` without using a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: I know that. So what's the point of adding uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: It's for having a UIViewController that contains only a UITableView without having to design a NIB and rewrite the same code every time. It's simply a specialized version of a UIViewController

Comment: The documentation states : "You create a custom subclass of UITableViewController for each table view that you want to manage." So I suppose you aren't supposed to use a `UITableView` directly but instead have to subclass it every time (which makes sense) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use UITableViewController without subclassing it.

Samplecode is very easy and straight forward.

For example like this:

```
- (IBAction)selectSomeOption:(id)sender {
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
    tableViewController.title = "Select some option";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
}
```

and the UITableViewDatasource and Delegate methods go into the same class.

Sure, if you like pain you could create a UIViewController in code and add a tableView on your own.
Or create a subclass for such an easy task.

The use of a non subclassed UITableViewController is sometimes convenient.